# deleted yarn.lock and commit changes but still getting lockfiles error

Tags: heroku, yarnpkg, package.json

I deleted yarn.lock and commit changes but still getting lockfiles error.

```
  Counting objects: 24375, done.
        Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
        Compressing objects: 100% (17171/17171), done.
        Writing objects: 100% (24375/24375), 30.34 MiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
        Total 24375 (delta 6150), reused 23977 (delta 5909)
        remote: Compressing source files... done.
        remote: Building source:
        remote: 
        remote: -----> Node.js app detected
        remote: 
        remote: -----> Build failed
        remote:  !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
        remote: 
        remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
        remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
        remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
        remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
        remote: 
        remote:        - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
        remote:          the yarn.lock file.
        remote: 
        remote:          $ git rm yarn.lock
        remote: 
        remote:        - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
        remote:          the package-lock.json file.
        remote: 
        remote:          $ git rm package-lock.json
        remote:     
        remote:        https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-conflicting-lock-files
        remote: 
        remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
        remote: 
        remote:  !     Push failed
        remote: Verifying deploy...
        remote: 
        remote: !   Push rejected to weight-tracker-react-rails.
        remote:
```

To https://git.heroku.com/weight-tracker-react-rails.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/weight-tracker-react-rails.git

'

Comment: Did you `git rm yarn.lock` or did you just delete the file itself?

Comment: that gives me fatal: pathspec 'yarn.lock' did not match any files so I deleted the file